# Hibernate/JPA mapping columns to Map type

Tags: hibernate, jpa, orm

Spring Boot, Hibernate/JPA and MySQL here. I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS fizzbuzzes (
    fizzbuzz_id BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    fizzbuzz_type_a VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
    fizzbuzz_type_b VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
    fizzbuzz_type_c VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
    fizzbuzz_type_d VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
    fizzbuzz_type_e VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
    fizzbuzz_type_f VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
    fizzbuzz_type_g VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
    fizzbuzz_type_h VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
    fizzbuzz_type_i VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
    fizzbuzz_type_j VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
    fizzbuzz_type_k VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
    fizzbuzz_type_l VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
    fizzbuzz_type_m VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
    fizzbuzz_type_n VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
    fizzbuzz_type_o VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
    fizzbuzz_type_p VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT pk_fizzbuzzes PRIMARY KEY (fizzbuzz_id);
);
```

I would like this table to O/R map to a JPA entity that has a **`Map<String,String>`** holding all of the fizzbuzz types A through P.

So instead of what you would typically see:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "fizzbuzzes")
public class Fizzbuzz {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "fizzbuzz_type_a")
    private String typeA;

    @Column(name = "fizzbuzz_type_a")
    private String typeB;

    // ...

    @Column(name = "fizzbuzz_type_a")
    private String typeP;

    // Getters, setters & ctors
}
```

...instead I'd like:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "fizzbuzzes")
public class Fizzbuzz {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "???")
    private Map<String,String> types;

    // Getters, setters & ctors
}
```

Where the keys of `types` might be hardcoded strings `typeA`, `typeB`, ..., `typeP` and the values of `types` would be the values from the respective columns in the DB table.

**Is this possible to do, and if so how?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sort of. It is possible if you are ok with having the type values in a separate table. Then you can use `@ElmentCollection` and `@MapKeyColumn`.

So for example:

```
@ElementCollection
@MapKeyColumn(name="type_key")
@Column(name="type_value")
@CollectionTable(name="fizzbuzz_types", joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="fizzbuzz_id"))
Map<String, String> types= new HashMap<>();
```

Otherwise, you need to hardcode the type columns as you have in your first sample, and you can add `@PostLoad` and `@PrePersist` hooks to convert static columns to/from transient map.

Something like:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "fizzbuzzes")
public class Fizzbuzz {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "fizzbuzz_type_a")
    private String typeA;

    @Column(name = "fizzbuzz_type_a")
    private String typeB;

    @Transient
    private Map<String, String> types = new HashMap<>();

    @PostLoad
    public void toMap() {
       this.types.put("typeA", this.typeA);
       this.types.put("typeB", this.typeB);
    }
    @PrePersist
    public void fromMap() {
       this.typeA = this.types.get("typeA");
       this.typeB= this.types.get("typeB");
    }
}
```